# VirtualBox increase VDI file actual size for Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, resize

I tried to increase the Actual size of the VDI image on My VirtualBox.
[image]

I followed this tutorial https://linuxhint.com/increase-virtualbox-disk-size/

After this when I run **df -f**

[image]

And when I use Gpartition I get following.

[image]

I am confused why it is not increasing.

When I try to import a database following **/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv** gets full with no space left.

Answer (score 1):

Your virtual disk is about 20.5GB in size but it is only using about 8.5GB on your physical disk. It's dynamic so as you use space in your VM the 8.5GB figure will increase. sda3 is about 19.5GB in size but only about 8.8GB has been given to your lvm. That means that about 10GB is unallocated. You need to research how to manage your lvm and in particlar how to add space to it.

https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/